# Using AudioBuffer as a source for a HTMLAudioElement?

Tags: javascript, javascript-audio-api

How one can use decoded `AudioBuffer` data to be set as a source for `HTMLAudioElement`?

Let us assume we have an `HTMLAudioElement`:

```
let audio = new Audio();
```

And we also were able to receive and decode audio data:

```
let context = new AudioContext();
let source = context.createBufferSource(); //this represents the audio source. We need to now populate it with binary data.

Api.getAudioFile(url).then((data) => {
  context.decodeAudioData(data, (buffer) => {
    source.buffer = buffer;
  }, null);
});
```

How one can use `source` as a source for an `audio`? I assume I have to create a `MediaStream` object for that matter, but it's not quite clear how to do it.

Comment: Simple solution, set the src of your Audio to `url`.

Comment: that's not the case if you fetch your audio from a server that requires auth token to be provided as a header.

Comment: Then make a Blob from your downloaded ArrayBuffer and set your audio src to a blobURI pointing to this Blob: `.then(data=>audio.src =URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data])))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is obviously to set the src of your AudioElement to the `url` you are fetching the data from.

In your case, it seems it's not that easy (because you need some credentials to passed along the request), in that case, if you can, make your response a Blob instead of an ArrayBuffer, and then simply set your AudioElement's src to a blobURI you'd have created from this Blob.

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
const url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3";

fetch(url)
  .then(r => r.blob()) // request as Blob
  .then(blob => audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob))
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>
```

And if you can't modify your request, or just need that ArrayBuffer e.g for the web audio context, then simply create a Blob from it:

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
const url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3";

fetch(url)
  .then(r => r.arrayBuffer()) // request as ArrayBuffer
  .then(buffer => {
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]));
    const ctx = new AudioContext();
    return ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer);
  })
  .then(console.log);
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>
```

Comment: Many thanks for that answer!  
Fixed my issue loading a OneDrive shared file into an HtmlAudioElement and bypass the CORS issue when using AudioContext on top of it